# Problem in creating trigger

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a trigger but get this error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE": syntax error: CREATE TRIGGER fk_item_place  BEFORE INSERT  ON  CREATE TABLE Item_Place(PlaceIDfk INTEGER ,ItemID NTEGER  , FOREIGN KEY (PlaceIDfk) REFERENCES Place_Table(Place_ID ) ON DELETE CASCADE  FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFERENCES ContentTable(ContentID)); FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT Place_ID FROM Place_Table WHERE Place_ID=new.PlaceIDfk ) IS NULL) THEN RAISE (ABORT,'Foreign Key Violation') END ;  END ;

My code is this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER fk_item_place " +
            " BEFORE INSERT "+
            " ON "+ Item_places +
            " FOR EACH ROW BEGIN "+
            " SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT "+ PlaceID +" FROM "+ PlaceTable +" WHERE "+ PlaceID +"=new." + place_id + " ) IS NULL)"+
            " THEN RAISE (ABORT,'Foreign Key Violation') END ;" +
            "  END ;");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `ON CREATE TABLE` trigger. Make sure `Item_places` is the table name, not it's DDL.

Comment: thank you so0000000000000 much i was at mistake table name is actually **Item_place** and im so dum code it as **Item_places**

Comment: @kshf_x Could you please mark Mat's answer as the correct answer?!